# Subtract models.DateField to get number of days

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a simple model that tracks work leave requests:

```
class LeaveRequest(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=False, null=False)
    submit_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    start_date = models.DateField(("Date"))
    return_date = models.DateField(("Date"))
    total_days = models.IntegerField()
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.employee, self.submit_date)

        class Admin: 
                pass

        class Meta:
                ordering = ['-submit_date']
```

In the view I need a function to calculate the number of days requested. Secondarily, I'll need a method to count only weekdays, but for now I've got the following:

```
def leave_screen(request, id):
    records = LeaveRequest.objects.filter(employee=id)
    total_days = LeaveRequest.return_date - LeaveRequest.start_date
    tpl = 'vacation/leave_request.html'
    return render_to_response(tpl, {'records': records })
```

which produces a attribute error

```
type object 'LeaveRequest' has no attribute 'return_date
```

any suggestions?

Comment: what are you tring to achieve in this view? Is this view suppose to display a particular leave record or list all the leave requests for a particular employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have 'total_days' as a field in the LeaveRequest class, but rather as a property.

```
class LeaveRequest(models.Model):
    (other fields)

    @property
    def total_days(self):
        oneday = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        dt = self.start_date
        total_days = 0
        while(dt <= self.return_date):
            if not dt.isoweekday() in (6, 7):
                total_days += 1
            dt += oneday
        return totaldays

# view function
def leave_screen(request, id):
    # get leave request by id
    leavereq = LeaveRequest.objects.get(id=id)
    return render_to_response("vacation/leave_request.html", {"leavereq": leavereq})

# template code
...
<body>
    {{ leavereq.total_days }}
</body>
```

Comment: I get invalid syntax error here "total_days(self)". I think this is the approach that I need, I just need to get the syntax right.

Comment: shouldn't it be if not dt.isoweekday() in (6,7)

Answer (score 1):

In total_days, you are calling the model and not the instance of that model - `records` - that you created.

If you want to view just a single Leave record, you would need to pass the id of the `LeaveRequest`

```
def leave_screen(request, id):
    records = LeaveRequest.objects.get(id=id)
    total_days = records.return_date - records.start_date
    tpl = 'vacation/leave_request.html'
    return render_to_response(tpl, {'records': records })
```

Comment: I've tried 'records.return_date' and I get another attribute error, ''QuerySet' object has no attribute 'return_date''

Comment: I've edited my post. In `records` change from `.filter` to `.get`. This will return a single object.

Comment: the answer might still not work after get if this view is suppose to list all the leaves for an employee as you will get mulitple records for a get call which raise another exception.

Comment: can't use get-raises a template error "Caught TypeError while rendering: 'LeaveRequest' object is not iterable"

Comment: what are you tring to achieve in this view? Is this view suppose to display a particular leave record or list all the leave requests for a particular employee

Comment: one particular leave record

Comment: This is a design flaw then unfortunately. You can pass the id of the `LeaveRequest` instead of the `employee id` and retrieve one `LeaveRequest` record - then my post would work. If you need to get all records you could go back to filter, then you would need to sum both dates before you subtract them - giving you the total leave requested.

Comment: "can't use get-raises a template error "Caught TypeError while rendering: 'LeaveRequest' object is not iterable"" -- if you are looking to pull one single `LeaveRequest` record then you won't be able to iterate over it in the template.

Comment: the idea was to tie the record called to the logged-in user. that's the reason for passing the employee id.

Comment: so you could put `if request.user == records.employee: ~continue else: render original page`, or you could only show the LeaveRequests of that user on the page using the same method, then allow them to click each leave request calling this function - so if this function is called it is definitely by the correct user. I see what you're trying to do, but you're design is going to need to change a bit.

Comment: total_days here is a timedelta object. to get the number of days from it do delta.days

Comment: @Dan-Your points are well taken and greatly appreciated. getting a workable design approach is exactly what I'm after. möter - greatly appreciate your suggestions as well. Will work with these and get back to you when I get the code working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that suggests using it as a property will work but I think I'll prefer keeping it as a field and just computing it at the time of insert.

```
class LeaveRequest(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=False, null=False)
    submit_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    start_date = models.DateField(("Date"))
    return_date = models.DateField(("Date"))
    total_days = models.IntegerField()
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.employee, self.submit_date)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_days = (self.return_date - self.start_date).days
        super(LeaveRequest, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        class Admin: 
                pass

        class Meta:
                ordering = ['-submit_date']
```

This way when you put in the logic for excluding weekends you are saving computation to calculate the days everytime at the time of listing all leave requests.

Comment: This is good. I totally overlooked the fact that `total_days` is being saved to the Model - so you would need to override the Save method and calculate it there. Then you can use your `leave_screen` function with one line `records = LeaveRequest.objects.filter(employee=id)`, and call `records.total_days` upon iteration.